# MongoDB Substring matching query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string, mongodb, substring

My application is trying to match an incoming string against documents in my Mongo Database where a field has a list of keywords. The goal is to see if the keywords are present in the string.

Here's an example:

Incoming string:

```
"John Doe is from Florida and is a fan of American Express"
```

the field for the documents in the MongoDB has a value such as:

```
in_words: "georgia,american express"
```

So, the database record has inwords or keywords separate by comman and some of them are two words or more.

Currently, my RoR application pulls the documents and pulls the inwords for each one issuing a split(',') command on the inwords, then loops through each one and sees if it is present in the string.

I really want to find a way to push this type of search into the actual database query in order to speed up the processing. I could change the in_words in the database to an array such as follows:

```
in_words: ["georgia", "american express"]
```

but I'm still not sure how to query this?

To Sum up, my goal is to find the person that matches an incoming string by comparing a list of inwords/keywords for that person against the incoming string. And do this query all in the database layer.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely split the in_words into an array as a first step.

Your query is still a tricky one.

Next consider using a [$regex](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions) query against that array field.

Constructing the regex will be a bit hard since you want to match any single word from your input string, or, it appears any pair of works (how many words??).  You may get some further ideas for how to construct a suitable regex from my blog entry [here](http://blog.abodit.com/2011/11/mongodb-substring-search-with-a-difference/) where I am matching a substring of the input string against the database (the inverse of a normal LIKE operation).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by splitting the long string into seperate tokens and put them in to the separate array. And use `$all` query to effectively find the matching keywords.

Check out the sample

```
> db.splitter.insert({tags:'John Doe is from Florida and is a fan of American Express'.split(' ')})
> db.splitter.insert({tags:'John Doe is a super man'.split(' ')})
> db.splitter.insert({tags:'John cena is a dummy'.split(' ')})
> db.splitter.insert({tags:'the rock rocks'.split(' ')})
```

and when you query

```
> db.splitter.find({tags:{$all:['John','Doe']}})
```

it would return

```
> db.splitter.find({tags:{$all:['John','Doe']}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f9435fa3dd9f18b05e6e330"), "tags" : [  "John",     "Doe",  "is",   "from",     "Florida",  "and",  "is",   "a",    "fan",  "of",   "American",     "Express" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f9436083dd9f18b05e6e331"), "tags" : [ "John", "Doe", "is", "a", "super", "man" ] }
```

And remember, this operation is case-sensitive.

If you are looking for a partial match, use `$in` instead `$all`

Also you probably need to remove the noise words('a','the','is'...) before insert for accurate results.

I hope it is clear

Comment: I believe you've misinterpreted the question. The long string is the query string, and the OP says nothing about needing to add it to the DB...